# Print php array in python

Tags: php, python

I have an array in php that I would like to print in python

```
php 
return array();

python code
value=os.system("php path/to/file"); // returns array
print value 

//output 
0
```

How do I print out the values of value?

Comment: `return` only works in a function, it returns it to the caller. It doesn't do anything at top-level of a script.

Comment: You should use `echo json_encode($array)` in PHP. In Python, use `os.popen()` to execute the PHP script and read its output. Then use the `json` module in Python to parse it.